# DS Views Block Field page visibility settings

Tags: 8, display-suite

I have a Views block *Sectors*. I have created a DS block field that renders this view and I have configured it to be available only for specific `bundle|view_mode`. It gets displayed on every `bundle|view_mode` page after that.

I wan't to configure this block to be visible only on a certain page(s) and not in all `bundle|view_mode` specified. Basically, I need a **Show block on specific pages** settings as in D7.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the block in `/admin/structure/block` and make so it visible on certain pages?

Comment: I wanted to but the block doesn't appear there.

Comment: @VladStratulat, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `/admin/structure/block` under the disabled region, click on <kbd>Place block</kbd> button and try searching for it on the search box, if you find it, place it and then <kbd>Configure</kbd>.

Comment: The DS field doesn't respect the block visibility settings. In D7 there was *Respect Block Visibility* setting to make it work but I can't find this option in D8. So I just replaced the field with normal block.